# State transition with `State`

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I'm trying to design state transition using `State` monad. I'm actually have a `java.nio.ReadableByteChannel` and I want to read it by fixed size chunks (e.g. 4096 bytes) and then combine some record from these chunks (e.g. by lines).

To stay in pure FP style I defined type Chunker:

```
type Chunker = 
  (List[Array[Byte]], Array[Byte]) => (List[Array[Byte]], Option[Array[Byte]])
```

And now define state transition recursively using the provided chunker as follows:

```
def takeFirstElement(chunker: Chunker)(chunk: => Option[Array[Byte]]):
  State[List[Array[Byte]], Option[Array[Byte]]] =
  chunk match {
    case None => State.pure(None)
    case Some(ba) => scanNextChunk(chunker)(ba) flatMap {
      case None => takeFirstElement(chunker)(chunk)
      case v @ Some(a) => State.pure(v)
    }
  }

def scanNextChunk(chunker: Chunker)(chunk: Array[Byte]):
  State[List[Array[Byte]], Option[Array[Byte]]] = State(chunker(_, chunk))
```

Now I wrote a simple test for it

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val chunker: Chunker = //some complicated chunker
    val channel = //some channel
    val buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8)

    val result = takeFirstElement(chunker) {
      val bytesRead = channel.read(buf)
      val data = if (bytesRead >= 0) {
        val ba = new Array[Byte](bytesRead)
        System.arraycopy(buf.array(), 0, ba, 0, bytesRead)
        Some(ba)
      } else
        None
      buf.clear()
      data
    }.run(List.empty)
    println(new String(result.value._2.get))
}
```

It works, but there are some things that are bothering me here in this example.

1. Can I make use of `ReaderWriterStateT` and replace by-name parameters with defined reader. Is it possible?
2. Is it possible to add `IO` semantic here to suspend side-effects the `channel` provides?

Comment: Have you considered using fs2 for the streaming abstraction?

Comment: @Reactormonk Sure, but for my specific task I need to read the first record from the given channel and determine a possition I need to `jump` to in the channel (`SeeakableByteChannel` and `ReadableByteChannel` have different way of seeking) . So I assumed that creating an fs2 stream logically goes after determining the actuall offset of the channel.

Comment: Is this `Chunker` type something that you're going to reuse? i.e. supply many different chunkers? I ask because, IMO, this looks a bit over abstracted for reading a chunk of bytes from a stream before publishing the rest of thre stream. Also, you use a by name parameter but then immediately match on, leaving no chance for it to go unevaluated?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Actually yes, my current intention is to reuse the chunker to `scan` the `fs2` stream in order to produce the chunks I need, not just a fixed sized buffer read from a channel.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov But I also use the by-name parameter after matching on it (twice in total). Does it look too weird?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Anyway would `Reader` be appropriate a the situation like this? Or it just introduces one more level of abstraction and makes the less readable? I mean to replace by-name parameters with `ReaderWriterStateT`